# I don't understand the difference between slightly and a bit?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions, differences

What is the difference in meaning or usage between *slightly* and *a bit*?

For example, the sentence:

> I thought she was younger than me, but in fact she proved to be **even slightly** older.

Is this correct? Or I should say:

> I thought she was younger than me, but in fact she proved to be **even a bit** older.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168226/what-is-the-formal-way-to-say-a-bit

Comment: Have you checked a good dictionary?

Comment: They're a bit different, but only slightly.  However, your sentence would work better if you dropped "even".  "Even" is a intensifier in this sort of context and it makes no sense to intensify "slightly" or "a bit".

Comment: Will someone chime in and correct me if I'm wrong..?  It seems that in AmE "slightly" is used more often in a sarcastic sense; (the opposite of "slightly") while in BrE "a bit" means "a whole lot", more often than not.

Comment: The difference is not in the meaning but in the metaphor. _A bit_ is count/unitary/digital/integer, _slightly_ is mass/continuous/analog/real number. One has volume, but only in countable bits and pieces, the other has continously variable volume (or area, or length, or voltage, or any other dimension), with only arbitrary divisions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use either *slightly* or *a bit* here; there is negligible difference in meaning.

However, the use of  **even** is not appropriate.  You are *contrasting  opposites* ("younger . . .but in fact .  . . older), not *comparing magnitude in the same direction* , where **even** would be appropriate ("he was old, but she was **even** older")

Comment: Oh, you could say _even_ that way, provided you gave it the right intonation; it would probly sound better as _to even be slightly older_, or _even proved to be slightly older_, better yet. The focus of _even_ is really the whole VP 'proved to be slightly older' -- that's the extreme, surprising phenomenon that _even_ is commenting on -- so right before that VP is its natural slot, though it can be floated, like many operators, to other positions in the clause.